# How to find entries in one file that match another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file (file1) with the following contents:

```
ENST00000364447.1   116 16.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000364424.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000364180.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000384451.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000362957.1   109 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000362478.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000384227.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000365615.1   107 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
ENST00000517091.1   106 17.000  0.000000    0.000000
```

I need to find entries in column 1 of this file that match text within column 10 of another file (file2):

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000243485.5"; gene_type "lincRNA"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.3"; level 2; tag "ncRNA_host"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000959.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  29554   31097   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000243485.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000473358.1"; gene_type "lincRNA"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.3"; transcript_type "lincRNA"; transcript_name "RP11-34P13.3-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "5"; tag "not_best_in_genome_evidence"; tag "dotter_confirmed"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000959.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002840.1";
```

In column 10 the name is in "".

I have tried `grep -F -f file1 file2 > file3`, but it is incredibly slow.  I've also tried a few different awk, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `file1` and `file2` in your post?

Comment: The two files I pasted.  I edited accordingly

Comment: How many rows in the files?

Comment: About 350,000..

Answer (score 1):

pure awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{gsub(/[";]/,"",$10);F[$10];next}( $1 in F )' FilterFile2 DataFile1
```

if performance and size is huge (>10000 filter) an alternative could be

```
awk '{gsub(/[";]/,"",$10);print "^" $10 "[[:blank:]]"}' FilterFile2 > CleanFilter 
grep -E -f  CleanFilter DataFile1
```

Comment: The first solution isn't working, it returns a blank file.  The awk part of the second solution seems to work, though the output is "ENSG00000243485.5";[[:blank:]] for each row.  grep is running now...very...slowly...

Comment: need some cleaning of the field 10, code modified. Your sample return empty result but if you add a value in filter that is in your data, it return corresponding lines

Comment: I don't understand.  I need it to go through column 10 for file2 and for every entry search in column 1 of file1 and if the entry matches then make a new file of the matching entries

Comment: right but your column 10 in file2 is not formated the same way as file1. You have surrounding quote and a `;`

Comment: Right, can I not search within that column for the specific text found in file1?  Or must I clean up the column in file2 first?